# Cannot Boot into Windows after removing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu and Windows in a dual boot setup. There are 2 SSDs on one I installed Ubuntu on the other one I installed Windows 10. I just removed the SSD with Ubuntu and thought that the Windows will work fine. But it's not. Windows is not loading and showing no boot device. I tried /FixBoot and /FixMBR. I even converted the drive to MBR but didn't help. Then converted back to GPT. I even tried to find the directory and manually add it to the UEFI boot menu didn't work either.

**Can someone help me to rectify the issue?**

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the Windows Boot Manager is corrupted, as earlier it was dependent on the EFI partition on the other SSD. There is nothing you can do about it. Your best option is to live boot into Ubuntu (or any other distro), backup your files from Windows, and then reinstall Windows.

I am telling you by my experience, I tried every possible solution to get it (for almost 1 week, I used to try daily for 4 hours or so), but somewhere I read the solution I posted. You cannot really do anything.

You could try to repair the boot manager, but I am not sure how to do it, or what are the chances of its success.

Answer (score 0):

In EFI system, you can choose which OS to boot through BIOS boot manager.
You can try to select the appropriate Boot menu in BIOS.